# how to compare chronometer time to text view in android?

Tags: android

I am using a chronometer for counting time in an app it has three buttons start,pause,reset.Once start button has clicked then only pause button should be enabled for clicking and start button should loose it's clicking functionality until the user presses pause or reset button.How to compare the chronometer time with a fixed time in a text view in android can anyone provide me a suitable way in this dilemma

Comment: i don't understand the question

Comment: on starting chronometer by clicking start-button that should enable pause button and disable start button and compare the time with a fixed time in a textview

Comment: yes? and what have you tried? (also, that's not a dilemma)

Comment: See i am not a good spokeperson but i want to achieve above  can you help me

Comment: doesn't change the question : "what have you tried?"

Answer (score 1):

Usually this is accomplished with a simple subtraction between two `long` values which represent a particular instant.

You use an instance of the [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class to bridge between an actual time (represented by a [`Date`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html) object) and a textual representation like `12:32`. Example

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
Date start = sdf.parse(text.getText().toString());
Date end   = sdf.parse(chronometer.getText().toString());
long difference = end.getTime() - start.getTime();
```

Regarding the listener part, either you remove listeners or check for some flag at the beginning of the `onClick(View)` callback. You may want to enforce the enabled/disabled state with some custom style if appropriate and `setEnabled(boolean)`

Answer (score 0):

is that what you're looking for?chronometer.getText().toString().equals(yourTextView.getText()) 
if not, please explain your question

Comment: yeah i already did thatit should compare when i click on stop button i have written that in if condition bbut not working